# How to observe ViewModel that makes a request for a call back

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, android-livedata

I am trying to make a request to a library that gives me a call back.

```
Manager.getInstance().request(new CallBack())
```

I want to put this in a ViewModel so that I can observe it from the `Activity`.

```
class RequestViewModel : ViewModel, CallBack {

    fun request() {
        Manager.getInstance().request(this)
    }

    override fun onFinished(result : List<String>?) {
    }

    override fun onFailed() {
    }
}
```

How can I make it so that I can observe when this has finished? I know I could make my `Activity` implement this `CallBack`, but I don't want to couple `Activity` to this.

Ideally this would be a LiveData or Observable.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you can submit the data acquired in `onFinished` method to the `LiveData` instance that should be observed by a view component, e.g.

```
class RequestViewModel : ViewModel, CallBack {

    private val _liveData = MutableLiveData<SomeResult<List<String>>>
    val liveData: LiveData<SomeResult<List<String>>> get() = _liveData

    fun request() {
        Manager.getInstance().request(this)
    }

    override fun onFinished(result : List<String>?) {
        if (result != null) {
            _liveData.postValue(SomeResult.success(result))
        } else {
            _liveData.postValue(SomeResult.failure())
        }
    }

    override fun onFailed() {
        _liveData.postValue(SomeResult.failure())
    }
}
```

And somewhere in your object that corresponds to a view component:

```
viewModel.liveData.observe(lifecycleOwner, Observer<List<String>> {
    handleResponse(it)
})
```

whereas `lifecycleOwner` typically is your `AppCompatActivity` or `android.support.v4.Fragment` inheritor.

Comment: You might also want to consider just having a Callback instance just be a field or some anonymous instance inside ViewModel.  Just cleaner to hide it from the rest of the application if that Callback is only useful and relevant within that ViewModel.  The rest of the above answer is how I would do it as well, just have the Activity observe the results via a LiveData as opposed to implementing the Callback interface itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to decouple requesting from `ViewModel` and create a class called Repository to handle all the requests. In this class you could have a `MutableLiveData` object which can be observed and whenever new requested data is retrieved, use `mutableLiveData.postValue(retrievedData)` for `MutableLiveData` which notifies the observes about the new changes.

To read more about repository, you can follow these links:

[Google's Guide to App Architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide)

[Codelab tutorial with Repository pattern](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#7)